# Как сделать отступ на следующую строку в java script

Tags: javascript

Как сделать отступ на следующую строку в java script?

Comment: отступ? может переход? Можете более подробно вопрос задать и с примером

Comment: @Асыл, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: @Асыл, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: вопрос из разряда: "Что у меня за полено выскочило?" -- "А, это вы кнопку Пуск нажали!"

Answer (score 1):

```
var lines = line + '\n' + secondLine;
```

Answer (score 1):

Новая строка в консоле - `console.log('something')` всегда выводит с новой строки. Также можно использовать [`\n`](http://jsfiddle.net/alvoro/pcxL20xu/). Вывод текста на страницу лучше производить с помощью таблиц стилей (css) и манипуляций с dom.

Comment: V console.log('something') ne dayot otstupa

Comment: Я даже смею предположу что это код выдает ошибку. Я же написал - console.log('someth\ning')